# Laravel: How to add a composite key (2 or more columns) as the $primaryKey in the related model?

Tags: php, laravel, composite-primary-key

Name of the primary key column in any model in Laravel framework is `id`

```
protected $primaryKey = 'id';
```

And I know I can change that default name like this:

```
protected $primaryKey = 'new_name';
```

My question is: What if I have a composite key (2 or more columns) in the table, how do I add them as the `$primaryKey`? And do I really have to define them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can put composite keys in models in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 8):

From the [Laravel docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/schema#adding-indexes):

```
$table->primary(array('first', 'last'));
```

Edit: I misunderstood the question. This thread might provide some answers: http://forumsarchive.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?pid=34475

Specifically overriding the `find()` method.

```
public static function find($primaryOne, $PrimaryTwo) {
    return Widget::where('primaryOne', '=', $primaryOne)
        ->where('PrimaryTwo', '=', $PrimaryTwo)
        ->first();
}
```

Comment: `$table->primary(array('first', 'last'))` usually used in the migration file while creating the table, I'm asking for `protected $primaryKey = 'id'` that exists in the related model file.

Comment: I'm in a bit over my head here but it doesn't look like Laravel supports that by default.

Comment: where this find method exist to override ? In my model class no such method to override.