# Any advantages of adding an id column to a pivot table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

Is there any advantages of having an id column in a pivot table (many to many relationship) in Laravel (i'm using version 5.1)?

With an id

```
        $table->increments('id');

        $table->integer('appointment_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('appointment_id')->references('id')->on('appointments')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
```

Without an id

```
        $table->integer('appointment_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('appointment_id')->references('id')->on('appointments')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->timestamps();
```

Comment: Does `$object->delete()` work if you don't have a primary key? (I think one is created automatically for `increments`, but my experience is mostly Laravel 4...)

Comment: Yes, it works for me, it deletes everything, the parent row and relations in my pivots tables, but I use delete Cascade.

Comment: It would be the same as having an auto-incrementing `id` column on a standard pivot table: it doesn't hurt to have one, but they're ultimately redundant, as you're (most likely) never going to be querying a pivot table directly. Example `SELECT * FROM pivot_table WHERE id = 5;` Unless you know that you specifically want that row, there's really no point.

Comment: Wouldn't it be useful for syncing in Laravel ? e.g `$user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]); `  http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships

Comment: Might make it easier to delete, but not by much, I would imagine. I noticed that with the model relations you define, I don't have much interaction with the pivot table itself... except for delete.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In general, the answer is no, provided that Laravel's Eloquent models are managing the relationship.

If, however, you need to access the tables from outside of Eloquent models (say, from another application or in the distant future when you rewrite your application to use the next big framework), an ID will come in handy.

Comment: Thanks, it makes sense.

Comment: old but, having a unique id in the pivot also lets you edit table entries directly from sql clients/sql workbench.

Answer (score 12):

Late answer, but you can remove the auto increment `id`, and use your foreign keys as a composite primary key for your pivot table:

```
$table->integer('appointment_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('appointment_id')->
    references('id')->on('appointments')->onDelete('cascade');

$table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('client_id')->
    references('id')->on('clients')->onDelete('cascade');

// add the following instruction

$table->primary(['appointment_id', 'client_id']);
```

Tested with Laravel 5.6, this works without breaking Eloquent's management while ensuring the uniqueness of the associations directly in your database structure.

[More about creating indexes...](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-indexes)

Comment: What? I always heard that composite keys are not, and will never be supported on Laravel

Comment: @nowox from the [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/migrations#creating-indexes) : "You may even pass an array of columns to an index method to create a compound (or composite) index". So I guess it is supported :)

Comment: Then I guess you can create tables with composite index, but you [cannot use in Eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31415545/2612235)

Answer (score 5):

Be careful while adding an id as primary key on pivot tables as it will "break" any validation on the foreign key couple unicity, meaning you could have multiple records having the same foreign keys couple.

Comment: Hmm, you're right. I guess, the only work around that is adding a unique index on both of the foreign key couple `$table->unique(array('appointment_id', 'client_id'));`

Comment: I do not think this should be an issue since the `id` column will be `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Comment: Yes, if you have an auto increment id field, then you need to do a unique pair constraint.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to set up MySQL Group Replication - you have to have the Primary key on every table.

> 17.7.1 Group Replication Requirements Server instances that you want to use for Group Replication must satisfy the following requirements.
>
> Infrastructure InnoDB Storage Engine.  Data must be stored in the
>   InnoDB transactional storage engine. Transactions are executed
>   optimistically and then, at commit time, are checked for conflicts. If
>   there are conflicts, in order to maintain consistency across the
>   group, some transactions are rolled back. This means that a
>   transactional storage engine is required. Moreover, InnoDB provides
>   some additional functionality that enables better management and
>   handling of conflicts when operating together with Group Replication.
>
> **Primary Keys.  Every table that is to be replicated by the group must
>   have a defined primary key, or primary key equivalent where the
>   equivalent is a non-null unique key. Such keys are required as a
>   unique identifier for every row within a table, enabling the system to
>   determine which transactions conflict by identifying exactly which
>   rows each transaction has modified.**
>
> IPv4 Network.  The group communication engine used by MySQL Group
>   Replication only supports IPv4. Therefore, Group Replication requires
>   an IPv4 network infrastructure.
>
> Network Performance.  Group Replication is designed to be deployed in
>   a cluster environment where server instances are very close to each
>   other, and is impacted by both network latency as well as network
>   bandwidth.

Comment: "...must have a defined primary key OR PRIMARY KEY EQUIVALENT where the equivalent is a non-null unique key" Adding the id on pivot tables is a big waste of time and space, not to mention the big issue with consistency, since you can have duplicated relationship between two entities. So, unless you have plans to make those pivot records actual entities, or are in fact Entities in your business, it is really an ugly design to have that extra id field

Comment: When I read that it does not seem to indicate the need for an incremental id field. It just says: it needs a primary key. The 2 values in a pivot table should be the primary key as far as I know. What they are asking in original post (I think), is whether you should put an incremental id field, like what most other tables have.