# Laravel Model with Two Primary Keys update

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, composite-primary-key

I'm trying to update Model which has two primary keys.

Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Inventory extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     */
    protected $table = 'inventories';

    /**
     * Indicates model primary keys.
     */
    protected $primaryKey = ['user_id', 'stock_id'];
...
```

Migration

```
Schema::create('inventories', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('stock_id')->unsigned();
    $table->bigInteger('quantity');

    $table->primary(['user_id', 'stock_id']);

    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
        ->onUpdate('restrict')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->foreign('stock_id')->references('id')->on('stocks')
        ->onUpdate('restrict')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

This is code which should update Inventory model, but it doesn't.

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('user_id', $user->id)->where('stock_id', $order->stock->id)->first();
$inventory->quantity += $order->quantity;
$inventory->save();
```

I get this error:

```
Illegal offset type
```

I also tried to use updateOrCreate() method. It doesn't work (I get same error).

Can anyone tell how Model with two primary key should be updated?

Comment: Illegal offset type, which type? has a line number? exists a inventory in this query?

Comment: ErrorException in laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php line 2762.
` /**
     * Get the casts array.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCasts()
    {
        if ($this->getIncrementing()) {
            return array_merge([
                $this->getKeyName() => 'int', // line 2762
            ], $this->casts);
        }

        return $this->casts;
    }
`
By the way, this inventory exists.

Comment: Paste in the full error so we can see the entire message in context.

Comment: Check this https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517 Laravel eloquent does not support composite primary keys. (Sidenote, you can't have two primary keys. Both fields are part of the one and only primary key)

Comment: Full error http://pastebin.com/yaG0aZYM

Answer (score 152, accepted):

I've run into this problem a couple of times. You need to override some properties:

```
protected $primaryKey = ['user_id', 'stock_id'];
public $incrementing = false;
```

and methods ([credit](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355#issuecomment-161376267)):

```
/**
 * Set the keys for a save update query.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    $keys = $this->getKeyName();
    if(!is_array($keys)){
        return parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
    }

    foreach($keys as $keyName){
        $query->where($keyName, '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName));
    }

    return $query;
}

/**
 * Get the primary key value for a save query.
 *
 * @param mixed $keyName
 * @return mixed
 */
protected function getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName = null)
{
    if(is_null($keyName)){
        $keyName = $this->getKeyName();
    }

    if (isset($this->original[$keyName])) {
        return $this->original[$keyName];
    }

    return $this->getAttribute($keyName);
}
```

Remember this code needs to reference Eloquent Builder class with

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
```

I suggest putting those methods in a `HasCompositePrimaryKey` Trait so you can just `use` it in any of your models that need it.

Comment: awsm. thanks! it really should be supported in the base framework tho....

Comment: yeah, I think it should. But I doubt it will ever happen

Comment: I've made a trait with this code, now I only need to `use CompositeKeyModelHelper;` on my Models. Thansk!

Comment: Added this to a model and it is failing. It appears something is calling getKey() in Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model before it calls either of the functions listed in this example, resulting in an error to be thrown since it isn't expecting an array for the attributes.

Comment: Do I need to call the methods `setKeysForSaveQuery` manually? Or are these methods only to tell the framework what to do in the background when calling `Mode_instance->save()`?

Comment: @Adam no, just override the methods, they will be used internally during the insert/update operations of the model

Comment: @Adam I think I haven't yet used this on 5.5, but you say `App\Lookup\Buil‌​der`... Maybe you are referencing a different `Builder` in the `use` statement?

Comment: Okay your right, I *was* using a differnet builder! I corrected it but its still not working: `Declaration of App\Lookup\CountryStats::setKeysForSaveQuery(Illu‌​minate\Database\Eloq‌​uent\Builder $query) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setKeysForSaveQuery(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query)`. I don't understand why because it has same parameter and visibility as the method in `Model`. I also noticed that `setKeysForSaveQuery` has no input parameter in `Model`.

Comment: @Adam you mean `getKeyForSaveQuery`? Yes, that shouldn't be a confilct but maybe there's no need to override that method. I think `$query->where($keyName, '=', $this->original[$keyName] ?? $this->getAttribute($keyName));` instead in the set method should work. I have not tried this though

Comment: @Adam On the other hand, I just tried this method as is and I have no declaration conflicts. It's weird that you do, since they are both the same method signature.

Comment: I'm getting the  ` Declaration of App\Models\Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey::setKeysForSaveQuery(App\Models\Traits\Builder $query) should be compatible with Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::setKeysForSaveQuery(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder $query) `

Comment: I'm getting the same error in Laravel 5.5

Comment: How would you go about doing this when your primary keys are id and year, where id should be incremented on add item? Also is this working with find()? Can I use ::find($id, $year)?

Comment: In case someone that used this solution is using soft deletes. You'll need to overwrite runSoftDelete too

https://pastebin.com/d3ED089R

Comment: Folks who are getting incompatibility errors need to add the following to their use statements in their model: `use \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;` because if you don't, it will look for `Builder` in the model's namespace (`App\Builder`) and not Eloquent's as it should be. @alepeino consider updating your answer include this into it as this question gets a lot of activity.

Comment: this is not working on laravel 8 ...

Comment: @AlbertoAcuña do `protected function setKeysForSaveQuery($query)` insead of `protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)`

Comment: Why not create a separate `id` key and keep the other two keep the combined unique key? anyone can please explain?