# Illegal offset type in isset or empty in foreach loop

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to update my table row in foreach loop, I have simplified it, but I am geting the same error over and over again.

```
$zaglavlje = App\Zagljavlje::where('broj_dokumenta','=',$request->zaglavljeId)->first();
$index = 0;

foreach(App\Stavke::where('zaglavlje_id', '=', $zaglavlje->id)->get() as $stavka) {
    $stavkaPromjena = App\Stavke::where('zaglavlje_id','=',$zaglavlje->id)
        ->where('stavka_id','=',$stavka->stavka_id)->first();
    $stavkaPromjena->kolicina = $request->kolicina[$index];
    $stavkaPromjena->save();
    $index++;
}
```

I have a POST request that gets values from an input tag

```
<input name="kolicina[]" type="number" max="{{$stavka->kolicina}}" min="1" value="{{ $stavka->kolicina }}">
```

The foreach loop has the same size as the array from POST I have checked it.

I am geting

> "Illegal offset type in isset or empty"

error.

The type in my database of this column is "decimal".

What am I missing here ?

Comment: It's going to be much more efficient to do `App\Stavke::first()` instead or `App\Stavke::all()->first()`.

Comment: Show your more code. and this is wrong App\Stavke::all()->first(); use App\Stavke::all() or App\Stavke::first()

Comment: I will update my question. Thank you

Comment: And your code doesn't make much sense, you doing same thing in a loop without using any loop variables

Comment: I have updated my question of what I am doing, hope it will help.

Comment: does your error indicate which line is causing the error ?

Comment: it did, "setKeysForSaveQuery()" function in Model.php class. That lead me to the solution for this. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If its any worth, the problem is that laravel/eloquent doesn't know how to handle composite primary keys. The answer to this is here:

[Laravel Model with Two Primary Keys update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332005/laravel-model-with-two-primary-keys-update)