# Why laravel delete() function getting error?

Tags: php, laravel, primary-key, primary-key-design

My table does not have a primary key.I want to use  **userId** and **cartId** together.

```
public function delete($uyeid,$Id){

    $this->getCart($Id)->delete();
}

 public function getCart($Id){
    try {
       $data = getCart::whereCartId($Id)->get();

        return $data;
    } catch(\Exception $e){
        return null;
    }
}
```

Should I define 2 column as primary?
how?

Comment: How does your Model look like? How does your Database structure look like? Where comes `whereCartId` comes from?

Comment: You have get $cartId and used $vartId in query please change it to 

$this->repo->getUserCart($cartId)->delete();

Comment: @ChristopherDosin whereCartId it just come from model i make it with ide_helper

Comment: @ManojPatel I edited my question

Comment: I believe you need to define the column name with their value in query like $this->repo->getUserCart('id',$cartId)->delete();

Comment: still same error :(

Comment: What does your relationship look like? Can you show us your table structure? Is userId logged in user id?

Comment: thank you I solved with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332005/laravel-model-with-two-primary-keys-update

Answer (score 0):

Please update your `deleteNote()`

```
public function deleteNote($uyeid,$cartId){

    $this->repo->getUserCart($cartId)->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line in **getUserCart()** function:

```
$data = getUserCart::whereCartId($cartId)->firstOrFail();
```

into

```
$data = getUserCart::find($cartId);

//OR

$data = getUserCart::where('CartId',$cartId)->firstOrFail();
```

The error occur in **where** clause. So change it and I hope it would helpful.