# SoftDelete doesn't work when I change primary key in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have changed the primary key in a table from id to pr_id and mobile.

```
$table->primary(['pr_id' , 'mobile']);
```

also I added SoftDelete Trait in model. but when I want to delete a record it doesn't work.

Comment: Try specifying your primary key in model. protected $primaryKey = 'your_key_name';

Comment: my primary keys are pr_id and mobile . i wrote protected $primaryKey=['pr_id','mobile']. but i goft other errors

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is because of not mentioning primary key into model, and your model still consider primary key is `id` however you have changed it. So you just to add following script into relevant model,

```
class YourModelClass extends Model
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'pr_id';
}
```

This in way model won't consider primary key as `id`.

Comment: my primary keys are pr_id and mobile . i wrote protected $primaryKey=['pr_id','mobile']. but i goft other errors

Comment: @aliFalahati can you show the errors that you are getting after mentioning key?

Comment: array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Answer (score 1):

You need to override few methods also like `getKeyForSaveQuery, setKeysForSaveQuery` with defining the primary key in model. For soft delete you need to override one more method `runSoftDelete`.

Reference links

- [For Save Query Method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332005/laravel-model-with-two-primary-keys-update)
- [For Soft Delete Method](https://pastebin.com/d3ED089R)