# Can't update a translatable model in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-translatable

I am using https://github.com/Astrotomic/laravel-translatable to make my models translatable.

While I am trying to update the model using below method to update the mode along with its associated translated content.

```
$product = $this->repository->update($input, $uuid);

   // output of dd($input);

  "uuid" => "44b26fb0-04b9-11eb-981a-6b01570d58ed"
  "_method" => "PUT"
  "en-us" => array:5 [▶]
  "ar-eg" => array:5 [▶]
  "account_uuid" => "a1c23ce0-04b7-11eb-b060-7faa78f23afd"
  "type" => "tour"
  "iso_4217" => "EGP"
  "status" => "pending"
```

I got this error:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'id' in 'where clause'
```

considering that the model primary key is "uuid" not "id" hence the foreign key is "product_uuid" not "product_id" as per below model setup.

```
class Product extends Model implements Transformable, TranslatableContract
{
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $keyType = 'string';
    public $timestamps = true;
    protected $primaryKey = 'uuid';

    public $translatedAttributes = [
        'name',
        'quantity_label_snigular',
        'quantity_label_plural',
        'brief_description',
        'long_description',
        'terms',
        'meta_keywords',
    ];

    public $translationForeignKey = 'product_uuid';
    public $localeKey = 'uuid';    
    public $useTranslationFallback = true;    
}
```

I followed the exact documentation at this link https://docs.astrotomic.info/laravel-translatable/usage/forms#saving-the-request, although I am not able to trace that error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that The issue was in the setup of the productTranslation model.

the 'product_translations' table primary key is a composite of 'product_uuid' and the 'locale'.

so in the 'ProductTranslation' model I defined the primary key as an array

```
protected $primaryKey = ['product_uuid', 'locale'];
```

and extended those methods to fetch the primary keys from array instead of string as per this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/37076437

```
    /**
     * Set the keys for a save update query.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
     */
    protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
    {
        $keys = $this->getKeyName();
        if(!is_array($keys)){
            return parent::setKeysForSaveQuery($query);
        }

        foreach($keys as $keyName){
            $query->where($keyName, '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName));
        }

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * Get the primary key value for a save query.
     *
     * @param mixed $keyName
     * @return mixed
     */
    protected function getKeyForSaveQuery($keyName = null)
    {
        if(is_null($keyName)){
            $keyName = $this->getKeyName();
        }

        if (isset($this->original[$keyName])) {
            return $this->original[$keyName];
        }

        return $this->getAttribute($keyName);
    }
```