# Can't update collection in Laravel eloquent

Tags: php, laravel

There is a table with the following structure: (primary keys: user_id, record_id)

```html
+---------+-----------+-------+
| user_id | record_id | value |
+---------+-----------+-------+
|       1 |         1 |   100 |
|       1 |         2 |   200 |
|       2 |         1 |   300 |
|       2 |         2 |   400 |
+---------+-----------+-------+
```

When i change **value** parameter over eloquent-query in my Controller like this:

```
$playerRecord = Test::where('user_id', '=', $player_id)->where('record_id', '=', '1')->first();
$playerRecord->value = $user_value1;            
$playerRecord->save();
```

I have an error: https://flareapp.io/share/47qg8ZEm#F49

If I define only one primary key in the model, all records with this key are updated, despite the fact that I forced to update a specific record.

Comment: u can use update() directly in your query

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36332005/laravel-model-with-two-primary-keys-update

Comment: Seems like this line throw an empty result `Test::where('user_id', '=', $player_id)->where('record_id', '=', '1')->first();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $playerRecord = Test::where('user_id', '=', $player_id)->where('record_id', '=', '1')->update(['value'=>$user_value1]);
    if($playerRecord){
     return "data updated";
}else{
    return "data not found";
}
```