# Laravel relations with composite foreign keys

Tags: laravel, eloquent, many-to-many, relationship

Here's what I want to achieve, we have Staff and every staff can have one **Position** for a department, as well as one **Designation** for a department and multiple **Additional Charges** for multiple departments, one department per **Additional Charge**. And I want to store all the responsibilities in the `staff_responsibilities` table

I have a `staff` table with the following columns

- id
- name
- email

Then I have `staff_responsibilities` table with the following columns:

- staff_id
- designation_id
- department_id
- responsibility_type_id

Responsibility types can be `Position` and `Additional Charge` and one staff can have multiple designations with `Additional Charge` responsibility.

Then I have a `responsibility_types` table with the following columns:

- id
- name

```php
// I have no way to tell this relationship to look for a responsibility type 2 (2 is the id of the responsibility called `Designation`) 

public function designation()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StaffResponsibility::class);
    }

// I have no way to tell this relationship to look for a responsibility type 2 
    public function position()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(StaffResponsibility::class);
    }

// Gives error: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'staff_responsibilities' 
    public function additionalCharges()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(StaffResponsibility::class, 'staff_responsibilities','designation_id');
    }
```

Any help would really be appreciated.

staff_responsibilities table

[image: staff_responsibilities]

responsibility_types table

[image: responsibility_types table]

designations table

[image: designations table]

Comment: I don't get why you want to use the compoships package. Seems like normale hasOne, HasMany and ManyToMany relationships.

Comment: Looks all fine. What is your problem?

Comment: The problem is it is not working as I intend it to.
Here's what i want:
when I do $staff->position it should return the first responsibility that has responsibility_type_id 1 (position)

And  when I do $staff->designation it should return the first responsibility that has responsibility_type_id 2 (designation)

Right now I have no way to tell my relationship to look for a particular responsibility_type_id when I call $staff->position or $staff->designation. they just return the first record that matches with the responsibility_id and staff_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's what I want to achieve, we have Staff and every staff can have one Position for a department, as well as one Designation for a department and multiple Additional Charges for multiple departments, one department per Additional Charge.

It sounds to me like it would be beneficial to create a model for **Position**, **Designation** and **Additional Charges**. It feels like you may need to [normalize your database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) or to change `staff_responsibilities` as a [pivot table](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many).

But hard to say without knowing your application.

To answer your question, you could add some scopes in `StaffResponsibility`

```
class StaffResponsibility extends Model{

    public function scopeDesignation($query)
    {
        return $query->where('responsibility_type_id','=',2);
    }

}
```

and use it

```
public function designation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(StaffResponsibility::class)->designation();
}
```

And the last one is a hasMany relation and not a manyToMany according to what you wrote:

```
public function additionalCharges()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(StaffResponsibility::class, 'staff_responsibilities','designation_id')->additionalCharges();
}
```

Comment: Designation and Position worked. Thanks! 

But `additionalCharegs` isn't working, it will be an HasMayn relationship I believe. but again same problem, it will display all the responsibilities.

Comment: I used the same `scope` approach and I'm getting the desired results with additionalCharges;

    public function additionalCharges()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(StaffResponsibility::class)->additionalCharges();
    }

Comment: @JunaidQadir why did you uncheck this?

Comment: @JunaidQadir I read you update. Your right its clunky, but it was the correct answer to your original post. I already said that it looks to me that you should rather use `Models` for `Position`, `Designation` etc. seems to be the better way which would also lead to `$staff->designation->name` etc. Also I find it very rude to modify your question and then uncheck my answer. If you have a new question, ask a new one instead. Maybe your new question fits better to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Well I didn't mean to be rude, sorry you felt that way but I was being honest with myself because I wasn't satisfied with the answer and still looking for a solution. I really appreciate you for chiming in and offer help

Comment: @JunaidQadir The update of you questions is as long as the OP. I would recommend you to 1) Create a new question 2) Try to make the example as minimal as possible - just state the problem with staff, positions and designation. Show code for each of the classes. My guess is, that `staff_responsibilities` should not be a Model but a pivot table, see https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many, but I am guessing in the dark

Comment: @JunaidQadir Another thing that comes to my mind, you can add the designation to `designation` method : `public function designation()
{
    return $this->hasOne(StaffResponsibility::class)->designation()->designation;
}` then you can access it with `$staff->designation`.