# Eloquent relation with composite key

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am using Eloquent, I managed to set up composite keys in laravel using the Trait as in this question here:

[How I can put composite keys in models in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5)

However, now I get the following error everywhere:

```
ErrorException in BelongsTo.php line 82:
Array to string conversion (View: /home/www/app/resources/views/relatorios/show.blade.php)
```

I understand this is because now my models have a composite primary key:

```
protected $primaryKey = array('cliente', 'id');
```

and in the relationship I have:

```
public function medico()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Medico','medico');
}
```

so this is of course wrong.

I tried to modify to:

```
public function medico()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Medico',['medico','cliente'],['id','cliente']);;
}
```

but no success.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because of how that trait works, you'd have to re-write all **13** of Eloquent's relationship definitions if you wish to use them with this trait. You shouldn't use composite key's in laravel.

Comment: The trait you refer to does not handle relationship definitions; what you might want to do in this case is "build" your entity ID by combining the IDs of both relationships, and keeping them separate as regular `indexes`.