# Composite primary key with Eloquent

Tags: eloquent

We want to implement Composite primary key with Eloquent ORM and Laravel 5 for http://www.mbarendezvous.com/ I understand it is not currently supported by Eloquent .
Please suggest what should be the best alternative for the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How I can put composite keys in models in Laravel 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 10):

I use the following code. It overwrites the original Model.php methods and takes all the primary keys into consideration. Put this into that model that uses a composite primary key:

```
protected function getKeyForSaveQuery()
{

    $primaryKeyForSaveQuery = array(count($this->primaryKey));

    foreach ($this->primaryKey as $i => $pKey) {
        $primaryKeyForSaveQuery[$i] = isset($this->original[$this->getKeyName()[$i]])
            ? $this->original[$this->getKeyName()[$i]]
            : $this->getAttribute($this->getKeyName()[$i]);
    }

    return $primaryKeyForSaveQuery;

}

/**
 * Set the keys for a save update query.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{

    foreach ($this->primaryKey as $i => $pKey) {
        $query->where($this->getKeyName()[$i], '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery()[$i]);
    }

    return $query;
}
```

EDIT:
Do not forget to add the following in your model class, otherwise this won't work.

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Comment: This worked, once I put in `public $incrementing = false;` at the top of my model.

Comment: Yes, good comment! It also took me a while to figure it out :)

Comment: I also had to add `protected $primaryKey = ['key1','key2','key3'];` since I had three different keys and none of them is `id`.

Answer (score 1):

You can override the `setKeysForSaveQuery` method from laravel's Model class.  You can change this method to:

```
/**
 * Set the keys for a save update query.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder
 */
protected function setKeysForSaveQuery(Builder $query)
{
    $query->where($this->getKeyName(), '=', $this->getKeyForSaveQuery());
    $query->where('secondKeyName', $this->secondKeyName); // <- added line

    return $query;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can override the save() method on your class that extends Model that has composite keys like the following:

```
public function save(array $options = array())
{
  $query = $this->newQueryWithoutScopes();
  // MY MODEL SPECIFIC FIX
  $query->where('OTHER_ID', '=', $this->OTHER_ID);
  // END MY FIX

 // the rest of the standard model->save() code is here but I cut it out for brevity. 
 // Use what is in Model.php already. 
}
```

I saw this solution here: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517

Comment: This will perfectly for an update, but it will not work correctly when the model will be created.

Answer (score -1):

in your migration use the following

```
$table->primary(['first', 'last']);
```

Ref Link: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/migrations#indexes

Comment: This will add an index and constraints. But eloquent will still not work with composite keys.