# Using Composite Primary Keys, Baum Nested Set Trait with Laravel Eloquent Models

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, composite-primary-key, nested-sets

I have a pretty specific issue here that I'm trying to work out, and I'm really not sure it's possible but I figured it's worth a shot.

I am using an Eloquent model to manage categories for FOUR different "sites" all in the same table.

The schema uses an ID and Site ID as composite primary key, which I made possible to use with Eloquent using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36995763/7380678).

The categories are implemented with a nested set model, so I wanted to use [Baum](https://github.com/etrepat/baum) to easily manage any operations on this data.

The issue is that I can't tell Baum that the primary key is composite, so it breaks whenever it tries to perform any operation on the table.

Has anyone encountered this issue before and figured out a solution, or is there a different solution that I would be able to use?