# Laravel - Array to string conversion

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I am trying to show the related applications to abstract, I have used the code below but I am getting this error

```
Array to string conversion
```

My controller

```
public function show($A_ID){

  $abstract = Project::find($A_ID);

  // I believe the issue is caused by the line below but I am not sure what is wrong about it 

  $applications = Application::find($A_ID);
  return view('Abstracts.show')->with('abstract', $abstract)
                             ->with($applications);
}
```

EDIT: (add model v1.0 and v1.1)

My model (v1.0) which show the error of `Array to string conversion`

```
<?php

namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey; 

class Application extends Model{


    //Table name
    protected $table = 'student_application';

    //composite key
    protected $primaryKey = array('A_ID', 'S_ID');
    protected $fillable = ['S_Justification' ];
    public $incrementing = false;}
```

My edited Model (V1.1)

```
    <?php
    namespace App;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey; 

    class Application extends Model{
    use HasCompositePrimaryKey; 


    //Table name
    protected $table = 'student_application';

    //composite key
    protected $primaryKey = array('A_ID', 'S_ID');
    protected $fillable = ['S_Justification' ];
    public $incrementing = false;}
```

I want to note that the composite key is declared using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5) number two with currently 59 votes

For more information here is my view

```
@if (count($applications)>0)
@foreach ($applications as $application)
<tr>
        <td><h5>{{$application->S_ID}}</h5></td>
</tr>
@endforeach
@else 
<p> This project has no applications </p>
@endif
```

Comment: have you included the required trait in your model?

Comment: yes I have already included it, also I have updated to model code you can see it now with include trait

Comment: there is a `find` method he is using, have you included it too?

Comment: I added the find method in the traits file

Comment: hmm `use Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey;` should be in your model, not above it! please make sure of it

Comment: As far as i know, find() returns only 1 row. 
so in your blade file you dont need to use @foreach, since it has only 1 row.

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din I tried your solution to move the use Traits but now it  this error 'shows Trait 'App\Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey' not found'

Comment: @MONSTEEEER the error is not from the blade file

Comment: where is your trait located? is it in your app directory? if not please add `use` statement above the class, and use it in your model like `use HasCompositePrimaryKey;`

Comment: it is in
 `app\Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey; ` do I have to move it or anything?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din Note: I have not edited anything in the traits file, I have copied and pasted it

Comment: Just fix your `use` and `namespace` statements of the trait and you are good to go.

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din I have changed my model to `use HasCompositePrimaryKey; ` and my namespace in trait  `namespace App;
` and still same error

Comment: if your trait is located in `app\traits` then trait namespace must be in `App\Traits`, and use it in your model like `use Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey;`. I hope it helps. if not please provide your project structure about traits

Comment: my app folder http://prntscr.com/m0x7ad , my Traits folder http://prntscr.com/m0x7hk , I useed the `namespace App\Traits` and the `use Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey;`

Comment: depending on images, try the following: `namespace App\Traits;` for your trait and in model add `use App\Traits\HasCompositePrimaryKey;` in top of the file and under the class definition add `use HasCompositePrimaryKey;`

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din Please check model v1.0 and model v1.1 which is the current code

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din Now I used your last suggestion and the error changed I believed the issue almost solve, my new error is related to the view which is `Undefined variable: applications` , Update: I have checked to return dd($applications) it returns null, am I finding it right ?

Comment: why did you make new class?? you have one, just add `use HasCompositePrimaryKey; ` to it!

Comment: Yeah I have removed the extra class already

Comment: so what is the problem now?

Comment: `$applications = Application::find($A_ID);` this return null while there are some applications for that certain $A_ID

Comment: well, I think `Array to string conversion` is solved, as I see $A_ID is just a part of your primary key, you have to provide full key.

Comment: recheck the link in your question for composite key, it may help you

Comment: I would thank you very much for all your help @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din

Comment: ^^ so does it work?

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din Now its works yeah, my current issue that this will show only for id of 201400858 `['A_ID' => $A_ID , 'S_ID' => '201400858' ]` I am searching how to say find all not just for 201400858

Comment: you may change the provided `find` method so it accepts `LIKE` instead of `=` and it may work with wildcard `*`

Comment: @AhmedNourJamalEl-Din The find method in the trait ?

Comment: yea,  and exactly this line `$query->where($key, '=', $id[$i]);` so it accepts `$operator` as parameter and pass it like this `$query->where($key, $operator, $id[$i]);`

Comment: I don't think I need to use that , I have just replaced `find` with `where` and added `->get()`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing string to view.

```
return view('Abstracts.show')->with(['abstract'=> $abstract)];
```

give it a try.

Edit: 
Or you can use like that.

```
with(array('order' => function($query)
```

Anyway you need to pass array in here. If you are just want to use -`>with('abstract');` you need to add abstract function. For example:

```
public function deliveries() {
       // this might be $this->hasOne... depends on what you need
     return $this->hasMany('Abstracts', 'conditions', 'id')->where('foo', '!=', 'bar');
    }
```

Comment: there is no issue with my return view with abstracts, the issue with applications

Comment: You can do samethings to the applications. Just give it a try. you can import applications in function($query) that works for sure.

Comment: can you clarify this line a little bit more `with(array('order' => function($query)
` I am not where and how to use it

Answer (score 0):

`$applications` is an object in your controller but you are accesing `$applications` as collection in your view file. You may try this:

```
$applications = Application::where('id', $A_ID)->get();

return view('Abstracts.show', compact('abstract', 'applications'));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, doesn't work. I believe my issue in this line  `$applications = Application::find($A_ID);`

Comment: `$applications = Application::where('id', $A_ID)->get()`