# Laravel composite primary keys relationship

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm trying to call this `hasOne` function, but I have 2 primary keys, how can I do it?

```
    public function user_ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User_rating', 'id_user', 'id');
    }
```

**User_rating table**

```
Schema::create('user_rating', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->integer('id_user')->unsigned(); //Increments es unsigned por defecto
            $table->integer('id_item')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('rating');
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->timestamps();

            $table->primary(['id_user', 'id_item']);

            $table->foreign('id_user')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('restrict')
                ->onDelete('cascade');

            $table->foreign('id_item')->references('id')->on('products')
                ->onUpdate('restrict')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

This is my database

[image: Database]

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/31415545/4468423

Comment: @erich That's from 2015, now they're supported

Answer (score 0):

```
    public function user_ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User_rating', 'id_user', 'id');
    }
```

The second param is the foreign key and the third is the local key.

Answer (score 0):

While the Laravel framework supports creating database tables with composite primary keys, *Eloquent* (the ORM) doesn't support them, and [probably](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5355#issuecomment-115426172) [never will](https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/22244#issuecomment-347841346).