# Cannot create multiple Primary Keys on Migration for Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I'm doing migrations for the DB of the enterprise I work for.

The issue is that the same table has 4 primary keys but this error is being throw by Laravel.

This is how my migrations look like:

```
Schema::create('ventas', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->integer('empresa_id')->primary();
        $table->integer('moneda_id')->primary();
        $table->integer('user_id')->primary();

        $table->foreign('empresa_id')->references('id')->on('empresas')->onDelete('restrict');
        $table->foreign('moneda_id')->references('id')->on('monedas')->onDelete('restrict');
```

How can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: every table can have only **one** primary key, but there are composite primary keays

Comment: How can I create a Composite PK?

Comment: you can have alook at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5 m but i personally find laralveland eloquent horrible

Comment: There's a difference between "three separate keys" (maybe one primary + two unique constraints) and a "single composite key" with three columns. Which one do you need?

Comment: You also seem to have an auto increment id field. If you have such a field, then you should make that the primary key, otherwise I would not understand why it's there.

Comment: I already tried the composite PK but it did not work. My task is to create this table with 4 PK but it seems that is not possible. I asked if I can have 3 Uniques and 1 PK but my supervisor told me: "NO".

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    public function up()
        {
            Schema::create('ventas', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->foreignId('empresa_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
                $table->foreignId('moneda_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
                $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->constrained()->onDelete('restrict');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
```

Comment: It tells me foreignid method does not exists :(

Comment: it work for  laravel 7 https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/migrations