# How to make composite/multiple primary key in Laravel >= 5.6?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a many-to-many relationship created between USERS and COURSES. The models and migrations are made as follows.

User Model:

```
public function courses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Course::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
```

Course Model:

```
public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'course_user', 'course_id', 'user_id')->withTimeStamps();
    }
```

The problem is I cannot find a way to implement a composite primary key into my migration file or pivot table in Laravel like this,

```
Schema::create('course_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->integer('course_id')->unsigned()->index()->primary();
        $table->foreign('course_id')->references('id')->on('courses');

        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index()->primary();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

After coding the above, when I call `php artisan migrate:refresh` an error appears showing multiple primary keys performed in the linked table. So I did a research on this matter and found out that ELOQUENT does not support composite primary keys as stated in this forum: [link to the forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5)

Is there any other way I can go around this?
I have somehow managed to write a piece of code to detect a existing entries in the pivot table or the many-to-many relationship, inside the controller and avoid new duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

To counter attack this problem I wrote a piece code in the controller to detect an existing tuple in the pivot table as follows. NOTE: I have used `Resources` to retrieve data, you can avoid the Resource functions and use the normal method also.

The `userId` and `courseId` are passed as parameters in the request:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
        $target = new AcademicPaymentResource(User::with('courses')->findOrFail($request['userId']));
        if ($target != null) 
        {
            foreach ($target as $query){
                // search for existing tuples
                foreach ($query->courses as $subQuery => $key){
                    // Check if courseId in existing tuple is equal to the courseId of request
                    if ( $query->courses[$subQuery]->pivot->course_id == $request['courseId']){
                        
                        // Do anything here..
                        // display data to test if it works
                        return $query->courses[$subQuery];
                    }
                    
                }

                // update the pivot table if the tuple doesnt exist
                $user = User::findOrFail($request['userId']);
                $user->courses()->attach($request['courseId']);
                
                // read tuple data again to display if it works
                $target = new AcademicPaymentResource(User::with('courses')->findOrFail($request['userId']));
                return $target;
            }
        }
    }
```

This method actually works fine, since I have used it flawlessly so far.
But if there is any other proper method please don't hesitate to answer..

Answer (score 0):

for people who are still landing here:

```php
$table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']); // Composite primary key
```